# when i click my update button it message SQL Error in syntax.

Tags: c#, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocWxp.jpg)
this is my code for update, and see what it tells after i run it. In the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61AX0.jpg)
and this will appear when i click the update button, i check all the possible errors but, cant fix it.

Comment: post the code rather posting an image

Comment: Error looks to me because of the single quotes in the values entered in the textboxes which are conflicting with the SQL syntax at runtime. The best solution to this is to user parameterized query. Pleas share your code.

Comment: Also why you need to update the serialnumber too if you are using the same value in WHERE clause? cmd.ExecuteNonQuery and cmd.ExectueReader() will run the same query twice. Any reason you want to do this ?

Comment: Actually im a beginner, i gather codes for guide and also examples, cant answer your question Chetan,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following solution. It uses parameterized query which will solve your issue.

```
con.Open();
var query = "UPDATE courseware_inventory SET title=@title, content=@content, pages=@pages, remarks=@remarks WHERE serialnumber=@serialnumber";

var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@serialnumber", txtSN.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", txtcour.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@content", txtCon.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pages", txtTP.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@remarks", cbRemarks.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Awesome, i was afraid to try this but. Now i am not :), Thanks a lot.